# .Net - passing variable number of arguments

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, system.reflection, reflection.emit

I need to handle the events from classes imported with Reflection. To do that I create a dynamic method with required argument types, then turn it to a delegate and add as event handler.

The only thing I need to do in dynamic method is making a call to a compiled method that receives a variable number of arguments. Thus I 'pack' any number of arguments of any type to pass it to a compiled method.

Here comes the trouble: it seems that I need to manually create the array in IL opcodes and fill it with arguments (which is a bit complicated), instead of just pushing all arguments on the stack (which is simple).

Here is the code (C++/CLI):

```
array<System::Type^> ^GetParameterTypes(System::Reflection::MethodInfo ^method)
{
    auto parameters = method->GetParameters();
    auto typeParameters = gcnew array<System::Type ^> (parameters->Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < parameters->Length; i++)
        typeParameters[i] = parameters[i]->ParameterType;
    return typeParameters;
}


ref class HandlerClass
{
public:

    void TestMethod(... array<System::Object ^> ^parameters)
    {
        System::Console::WriteLine("asdf");
    }
}


System::Delegate ^AddHandler(HandlerClass ^handler, System::Reflection::EventInfo ^_event, System::Object ^instance)
{
    // Get handler type
    auto delegateType = _event->EventHandlerType;
    assert(delegateType);

    auto invoke = delegateType->GetMethod("Invoke");
    assert(invoke);

    // Get return type
    auto returnType = invoke->ReturnType;

    // Get parameter list
    auto delegateParameters = GetParameterTypes(invoke);

    auto parameters = gcnew array<System::Type ^> (delegateParameters->Length + 1);
    parameters[0] = System::Object::typeid;
    delegateParameters->CopyTo(parameters, 1);

    // Create dynamic method
    auto handlerMethod = gcnew System::Reflection::Emit::DynamicMethod("",
                            returnType,
                            parameters,
                            ProxyEvent::typeid);

    auto method = HandlerClass::typeid->GetMethod("TestMethod");

    // Add method body
    auto codeGen = handlerMethod->GetILGenerator();

    // 'this' pointer
    codeGen->Emit(System::Reflection::Emit::OpCodes::Ldarg_0);

    // Parameters
    for (int i = 0; i < delegateParameters->Length; i++)
        codeGen->Emit(System::Reflection::Emit::OpCodes::Ldarg, i + 1);

    // Method call
    codeGen->Emit(System::Reflection::Emit::OpCodes::Call, method);
    //codeGen->EmitCall(System::Reflection::Emit::OpCodes::Call, method, parameters);   //This one throws an exception that calling convention should be Vararg

    // Return
    codeGen->Emit(System::Reflection::Emit::OpCodes::Ret);

    // Get delegate
    auto compiled = handlerMethod->CreateDelegate(delegateType, handler);

    // Add to handler list
    _event->AddEventHandler(instance, compiled);
}
```

So as you can see, my TestMethod function is not quite a real variadic function. C# equivalent would be `void TestMethod(params object[] parameters);`. That is because C++/CLI doesn't support `__arglist` keyword.
Thus this IL code is incorrect, I don't see any parameters in my `TestMethod`.

The question is: Is there a way to declare a variadic function (in C++/CLI) such that I would just pass push the parameters on the stack and call it?

If no, then is there a way to achieve similar results (pass the parameters to a compiled function from an event imported through Reflection) without using IL code generator at all?

Comment: You cannot bypass the rock hard requirement to create the array.  Normally the compiler does it for you, but when you generate IL yourself then it is your job.  Nothing to panic about, write a sample C# or C++/CLI program that uses a param array and just use a disassembler (like ildasm.exe) to look at the IL it generates.  Duplicate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10594/A-Universal-Event-Handler-Factory) tutorial I came up with the following code:

```
System::Reflection::Emit::DynamicMethod ^CreateHandler()
{
    // Get event handler type
    auto delegateType = _event->EventHandlerType;
    assert(delegateType);

    auto invoke = delegateType->GetMethod("Invoke");
    assert(invoke);

    // Get return type
    auto returnType = invoke->ReturnType;

    // Get parameters list
    auto delegateParameters = GetParameterTypes(invoke);

    // First parameter should be a pointer to my handler class
    auto parameters = gcnew array<System::Type ^> (delegateParameters->Length + 1);
    parameters[0] = MyHandlerClass::typeid;
    delegateParameters->CopyTo(parameters, 1);

    // Create dynanic method for my handler class
    auto handler = gcnew System::Reflection::Emit::DynamicMethod(
        _event->Name + "Handler",
        returnType,
        parameters,
        MyHandlerClass::typeid
    );

    // This method should be called
    auto method = MyHandlerClass::typeid->GetMethod("GeneralEventHandler");

    // Add method body
    auto codeGen = handler->GetILGenerator();

    // Get type of 'object[]'
    auto arrayType = System::Object::typeid->MakeArrayType();

    // Create local variable 'args' (at index 0) of type 'object[]'
    auto localArgs = codeGen->DeclareLocal(arrayType);

    // Create an array of arguments of required size
    codeGen->Emit(System::Reflection::Emit::OpCodes::Ldc_I4, delegateParameters->Length);   // Array size
    codeGen->Emit(System::Reflection::Emit::OpCodes::Newarr, System::Object::typeid);       // Creating array
    codeGen->Emit(System::Reflection::Emit::OpCodes::Stloc_0);                              // Store to local variable at index 0 ('args')

    // Fill array
    for (int i = 0; i < delegateParameters->Length; i++)
    {
        // Store (i + 1) argument to array at index i
        codeGen->Emit(System::Reflection::Emit::OpCodes::Ldloc_0);          // Refer to array
        codeGen->Emit(System::Reflection::Emit::OpCodes::Ldc_I4, i);        // Move to index i
        codeGen->Emit(System::Reflection::Emit::OpCodes::Ldarg_S, i + 1);   // Refer to (i + 1) argument

        // Is argument of simple type?
        if (delegateParameters[i]->IsValueType)
        {
            // Pack argument
            codeGen->Emit(System::Reflection::Emit::OpCodes::Box, delegateParameters[i]);
        }

        // Store element to array
        codeGen->Emit(System::Reflection::Emit::OpCodes::Stelem_Ref);
    }

    // Now we put everything on stack:
    // 'this' pointer
    codeGen->Emit(System::Reflection::Emit::OpCodes::Ldarg_0);

    // Nane of event (for identification)
    codeGen->Emit(System::Reflection::Emit::OpCodes::Ldstr, _event->Name);

    // Array of arguments
    codeGen->Emit(System::Reflection::Emit::OpCodes::Ldloc_0);

    // Now call the method
    codeGen->Emit(System::Reflection::Emit::OpCodes::Call, method);

    // And return
    codeGen->Emit(System::Reflection::Emit::OpCodes::Ret);

    return handler;
}
```

The handler class looks like this:

```
ref class MyHandlerClass
{
public:

    void GeneralEventHandler(System::String ^name, array<System::Object ^> ^params);
}
```

And then I just use this dynamic method to connect to the event:

```
System::Delegate ^Connect(System::Object ^instance, MyHandlerClass ^handler)
{
    auto method = CreateHandler();
    assert(method);

    // Создадим делегат
    auto delegate = method->CreateDelegate(_event->EventHandlerType, handler);
    assert(delegate);

    // Добавим в список обработчиков
    _event->AddEventHandler(instance, delegate);

    return delegate;
}
```

The code is written in C++/CLI but it's fairly easy to convert in to C#.

The idea is the same as in my initial post, I just added the array of objects generation code.

Answer (score 0):

You can define functions with a variable number of arguments in a C++/CLI "ref class" (managed class). The syntax requires the "..." token to be prepended to the array holding those arguments, and must be the last parameter in the function declaration. Example:

```
public: void SomeFunction (    int         iRequiredArgument1,
                               int         iRequiredArgument2,
                           ... array<int>^ aiVariableArguments)
    {
    // function implementation
    return;
    }
```

If the types of the variable arguments aren't known at compile time, use

```
array<Object^>^
```

and typecast its elements at runtime.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I already have a function with variable number of arguments. What I need is to fill the arguments and call it from MSIL code.